# Remote port forward works on TCP/1194 but not on TCP/443 even though port 443 on the server is not being used

Tags: permissions, ssh-tunnel, linode

I am having a weird issue.

I brought up a new Linode to act as a tunnelling endpoint.

I was able to successfully remote forward port 1194 so now connections to linode-server@1194 successfully to my machine's port 1194 and I am able to connect to my VPN by connecting to port 1194 on my linode-server.

The below command is what I used (the one that works):

```
ssh -N -R 1194:localhost:1194 user@linode-server.something.com
```

Now I want to port forward 443 as well. I tried this:

```
ssh -N -R 443:192.168.1.122:443 user@linode-server.something.com
```

My local server is listening on 192.168.1.122 on purpose (not localhost).

However, the above command fails to open port 443 on the server. I get the below error:

> Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 443

So I checked on my linode-server whether anything is running on port 443. Nothing is:

```
user@linode-server:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1194            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7438/sshd: user       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      411/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2377/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1513/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::1194                 :::*                    LISTEN      7438/sshd: user       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2377/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1513/master         
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           411/systemd-resolve 
user@linode-server:~$
```

There is no soft-firewall on the server. And the Linode cloud firewall have been switched off, I still can't do it.

I have absolutely no idea why forwarding 443 is not working.

P.S. - user authentication is working just fine while creating the tunnel.

I am not sure whether this will help, but my sshd_config looks like this:

```
user@linode-server:~$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -v "^#" | grep -v "^$"
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
GatewayPorts yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
user@linode-server:~$
```

And to clarify, there is nothing in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/`

Verbose logging form sshd on linode-server:

```
...
Aug 14 09:00:32 connect sshd[9499]: Postponed publickey for pi from *HIDDEN: My home public IP* port 49180 ssh2 [preauth]
Aug 14 09:00:32 connect sshd[9499]: Accepted key RSA *HIDDEN* found at /home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys:1
Aug 14 09:00:32 connect sshd[9499]: Accepted publickey for pi from *HIDDEN: My home public IP* port 49180 ssh2: RSA *HIDDEN* 
Aug 14 09:00:32 connect sshd[9499]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Aug 14 09:00:32 connect systemd-logind[578]: New session 157 of user pi.
Aug 14 09:00:32 connect sshd[9499]: User child is on pid 9579
Aug 14 09:00:32 connect sshd[9579]: bind [0.0.0.0]:443: Permission denied
Aug 14 09:00:32 connect sshd[9579]: error: bind [::]:443: Permission denied
Aug 14 09:00:32 connect sshd[9579]: error: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 443
...
```

Why is permission denied? The remote forwarding command I used above uses the same user (for both the successful and failed tunnel).

Just found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux) that it might be because 443 is a privileged port. Now I do not want to use root user to enable remote forwarding on 443. I have locked down the linode-server and can't be logged in as root (and I don't want to allow root login). As per the above link, I can use `setcap`, on the linode-server, but how do I do it since the tunnel open command is actually run from my local. What are my alternatives? I know maybe using a higher port on the linode-server will work, but I don't want to do that. I would really like it to be port 443 so I don't need to remember the port.

Comment: Have you also tried other low level port numbers e.g. 444?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On local server, initiated remote port forward from port 8080 instead (non-privileged port)

```
ssh -N -R 8080:192.168.1.122:443 user@linode-server.something.com
```

On linode-server, installed a tool called `socat` and used the below command to locally forward from 8080 to 443 on linode server and it works now :)

```
sudo socat TCP-LISTEN:443,fork TCP:0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: If it works accept your own answer!

Comment: Gives me: `:443 [...] Address already in use`, which of course is true, that's why I need my remote's 443 locally... Also odd is lsof -ti :443 returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is nothing is listening on port 443. There needs to be a process listening on port 443 in order for you to make connections to port 443. If you look at your netstat you'll see that you currently have a process listening on port 1194, which is why connections to port 1194 succeed. You need to change that process to listen on port 443.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1194            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7438/sshd: pi
```

Comment: I think you got it wrong there, buddy. The ssh remote port forwarding is supposed to open 443. You see 1194 open coz the remote port forwarding for 1194 worked.